# How to use "parse" on a <Input> (like <SearchInput>) without changing the format value?

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

Let's say I have a `<SearchInput>` and I want to convert it to lowerCase when I parse to send to server to query.

However, I don't want the Input to reflect the same thing. I thought `parse` only changes the data to send the server, but it reflects the Input box too (as if I also used `format`).

I can use `format` to change it back, but ... how do I even get "back", the original value before parsing?

For example:

```xml
<SearchInput
    source='lastNameLower'
    placeholder='Last Name'
    parse={ v => v && v.toLowerCase() }
/>
```

If I input "Foo" => parse sends `foo` (lowercase) to server successfully.
However, as if I also used `format=`, the Input value ALSO changes... **so how do I keep the original value and only parse for the server?**

Comment: I think you can try this just before the api call instead doing it in the component as it is reactive.

Answer (score 1):

Use the SearchInput as a controlled component by

- creating state to store the user input
- updating the state when the user types
- set the value of the input to the state variable
- when submitting, convert the input to lowercase and submit

I am not sure what your `SearchInput` component looks like or where its from, but the below is mockup which code will give you an idea.

```
const App = () => {

  const [searchInput, setSearchInput] = useState(""); //state for the search the user is inputting

  const onInput = (e) => {
    setSearchInput(e.target.value); //e.target.value is typical for html input, sometimes it will just be "value" if the SearchInput is from a package. You will need to look at the docs for this
  }

  //Lower case the input and submit
  const handleSubmit = () => {
    //convert the search input to a lowercase
    const submitVal = searchInput.toLowerCase();
    //call API endppoint 
    yourApi.call(submitVal).then(res => {
     //do what you wish with the results
    })
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <SearchInput
        source='lastNameLower'
        placeholder='Last Name'
        value={searchInput}
        onChange={onInput} 
      />
    <button onClick={handleSubmit}>submit</button>
   <div>
  )
}
```